# IE 11 send UrlReferrer = null, when i use http POST query with Japanese characters(Or arabic)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Using IE 11, i try to do a Http POST request with Japanese(or arabic)characters, i receive always a null in UrlReferrer param.

Note : 
- this issue occur in IE 11 (Windows 10 ), it work fine with Chorme, Firfox. 
- it work fine in IE 11 on Windows 7.

Comment: The code. Show us the code.

Comment: Try to use [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to debug your code and check whether it contains some error? Beside, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i'am not able to share the code and it's a complex environment.
It's an ASPX app, when i try to pass a parameter(in japanese characters) in QueryString with a Http POST request, the browser return UrlReferrer = null, it work fine  when i pass the parameter in Latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), the http Referrer returns a value only when the user reaches the current page through a link from the previous page. Otherwise, if the request is redirected to a page (Be it from the current web site or a different web site) using Response.Redirect, you will find the Request.UrlReferrer value to be null. So, I suggest could try to track to http request, whether it is redirected to another page.

Besides, if you want to get the previous page url, as a workaround, I think you could transfer it through parameters method.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, it was a problem on encoding, i resolved this issue with : 1) Encoding the user input (Japaneses characters) un base 64, 2)Decode user input to normal string. With this approach browser return the right UrlReferrer.